# Google Maps API not working correctly under safari

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, safari

If I do something like

```
map = new GMap2(document.getElementById(mapCanvas));
directions = new GDirections(map);
directions.load("SOME DIRECTIONS HERE");
```

Under firefox on LInux it works great!
Under safari it displays the map but not the directions.

What gives?

Comment: Always remember to declare variables with `var` (`map` is undeclared here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

The Google Maps API will not let you use GDirections without a valid API Key. Also you can't use an ip, so you have to use DNS.